# Store additional information in Django session in login response

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

After a user logs in, they're sent the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions) cookie inside an HttpResponse object. I want to add an additional field 'foo' to the session, just like I had done

```
request.session['foo'] = 'bar'
```

The above doesn't work because the login request itself doesn't have the session object itself, only subsequent requests have the cookie.

Also, doing

```
response.set_cookie("foo", "bar")
```

doesn't seem to associate the cookie with session (request.session['foo'] throws an error on subsequent requests).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using built-in login view or your own custom one?

Comment: Just the built-in login view.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using a custom login view, you can do something like this:

```
def custom_login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated
            # here, user is not logged in. 
            request.session['my_data'] = 'my value'

        return render(request, 'login.html' , {})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # get login credentials and authenticate user
        # see -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/homepage')
```

Or, if you want to use built-in login views, you can manipulate session data at middleware level. Just write a custom middleware like this:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        if request.path == '/login' and request.method == 'GET' and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.session['data'] = 123

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

And don't forget to add this `SimpleMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in `settings.py`. You can find more about middlewares [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/).

Comment: I actually also need the session value to depend on the logged-in user, e.g. "request.session['my_data'] = user.email". It seems like I can't pre-make a session for AnonymousUser with the desired data like you did in both of these?

Comment: @ChrisJones you can check `request.user.is_authenticated` value and set desired data based on user's authentication status. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: Whoops I was confused. Actually the first thing I thought didn't work does exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for the help!